# await Task.Delay(foo); takes seconds instead of ms

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

Using a variable delay in `Task.Delay` randomly takes seconds instead of milliseconds when combined with a IO-like operation.

Code to reproduce:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            Task[] wait = {
                              new delayTest().looper(5250, 20), 
                              new delayTest().looper(3500, 30),
                              new delayTest().looper(2625, 40), 
                              new delayTest().looper(2100, 50)
                          };
            Task.WaitAll(wait);

            Console.WriteLine("All Done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class delayTest {
        private Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        public delayTest() {
            sw.Start();
        }

        public async Task looper(int count, int delay) {
            var start = sw.Elapsed;
            Console.WriteLine("Start ({0}, {1})", count, delay);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                var before = sw.Elapsed;
                var totalDelay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(i * delay) + start;
                double wait = (totalDelay - sw.Elapsed).TotalMilliseconds;
                if (wait > 0) {
                    await Task.Delay((int)wait);
                    SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => false, 1);
                }
                var finalDelay = (sw.Elapsed - before).TotalMilliseconds;
                if (finalDelay > 30 + delay) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Slow ({0}, {1}): {4} Expected {2:0.0}ms got {3:0.0}ms", count, delay, wait, finalDelay, i);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done ({0}, {1})", count, delay);
        }
    }
}
```

Also reported this on [connect](https://github.com/Dorus/taskDelayProblem).

---

### Leaving old question bellow, for completeness.

I am running a task that reads from a network stream, then delays for 20ms, and reads again (doing 500 reads, this should take around 10 seconds). This works well when I only read with 1 task, but strange things happen when I have multiple tasks running, some with long (60 seconds) delay. My ms-delay tasks suddenly hang half way.

I am running the following [code](https://github.com/Dorus/taskDelayProblem) (simplified):

```
var sw = Stopwatch();
sw.Start()
await Task.Delay(20); // actually delay is 10, 20, 30 or 40;
if (sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds > 1) {
    Console.WriteLine("Sleep: {0:0.00}s", sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
}
```

This prints:

> Sleep: 11.87s

(Actually it gives the 20ms delay 99% of the time, those are ignored).

This delay is almost 600 times longer than expected. The same delay happens on 3 separate threads at the same time, and they all continue again at the same time also.

The 60 second sleeping task wakes up as normal ~40 seconds after the short tasks finish.

Half the time this problem does not even happen. The other half, it has a consistent delay of 11.5-12 seconds.  I would suspect a scheduling or thread-pool problem, but all threads should be free.

When I pause my program during the stuck phase, the main thread stacktrace stands on `Task.WaitAll`, 3 tasks are Scheduled on `await Task.Delay(20)` and one task is Scheduled on `await Task.Delay(60000)`. Also there are 4 more tasks Awaiting those first 4 tasks, reporting things like '"Task 24" is waiting on this object: "Task 5313" (Owned by thread 0)'. All 4 tasks say the waiting task is owned by thread 0. There are also 4 ContinueWith tasks that I think I can ignore.

[image: Scheduled tasks]

There are some other things going on, like a second console application that writes to the network stream, but one console application should not affect the other.

**I am completely clueless on this one. What is going on?**

Update:

Based on comments and questions:

When I run my program 4 times, 2-3 times it will hang for 10-15 seconds, 1-2 times it will operate as normal (and wont print "Sleep: {0:0.00}s".)

`Thread.Count` indeed goes up, but this happens regardless of the hang. I just had a run where it did not hang, and `Thread.Count` started at 24, wend up to 40 after 1 second, around 22 seconds the short tasks finished normal, and then `Thread.Count` wend down to 22 slowly over the next 40 seconds.

Some more code, full code is found in the link below. Starting clients:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

private void makeClient(int delay, int startDelay) {
    Task task = new ClientConnection(this, delay, startDelay).connectAsync();
    task.ContinueWith(_ => {
        lock (tasks) { tasks.Remove(task); }
    });
    lock (tasks) { tasks.Add(task); }
}

private void start() {
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine("Starting clients...");

    int[] iList = new[]  { 
        0,1,1,2,
        10, 20, 30, 40};
    foreach (int delay in iList) {
        makeClient(delay, 0); ;
    }
    makeClient(15, 40);
    Console.WriteLine("Done making");

    tasks.Add(displayThreads());

    waitForTasks(tasks);
    Console.WriteLine("All done.");
}

private static void waitForTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
    Task[] waitFor;
    lock (tasks) {
        waitFor = tasks.ToArray();
    }
    Task.WaitAll(waitFor);
}
```

Also, I tried to replace the `Delay(20)` with `await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(20))`
`Thread.Count` now goes from 29 to 43 and back down to 24, however among multiple runes it never hangs.

With or without `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(500, 500)`, using [`TaskExt.Delay` by noserati](https://gist.github.com/noserati/bf9432246cb9f0122c00) it does not hang. (That said, even switching over 1 line of code sometimes stops it from hanging, only to randomly continue after I restart the project 4 times, but I've tried this 6 times in a row without any problems now).

I've tried everything above with and without `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` so far, never made any difference.

Update2: [CODE!](https://github.com/Dorus/taskDelayProblem)

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem - it'll be a lot easier to help you that way. (We currently know nothing about your environment...)

Comment: Right now that would be two separate console programs with a lot of extra code. The biggest problem is the bug only pops up half the time, making small changes randomly eliminate it. But I'll see if I can cook something up.

Comment: Is there any SynchronizationContext set? Is the Task.WaitAll the *only* point where you wait for a task?

Comment: How do you create your tasks? If one task starts blocking when another is introducing a large delay, that suggests some sort of relationship.

Comment: I tried to simplify my program a bit, and, (it gets quite ridiculous), with a 1:1 copy to a different directory the problem vanish...... VS2013 now suddenly also becomes really crashy. Going to see if I can reboot and clean some stuff.

Comment: Not specific to the problem - others have commented on that.  However, you should be using a `StopWatch` instead of `DateTime.Now` to calculate timings.  See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ProperBenchmarkingToDiagnoseAndSolveANETSerializationBottleneck.aspx

Comment: Agreed, that did fix some of my <30ms measurement problems, but not this one. My 1:1 copy just started to throw this problem at me also, so it is not a unclean build, but the chance to see the problem does go up when you rebuild the project a couple time. I'm still just as puzzled.

Comment: @Dorus, try calling `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(500, 500)` at the very beginning of your app. Does it fix the issue?

Comment: Nope, still happening. It runs normal the first 7 seconds, hangs for 13s, and then finish around seconds 20-21.

Comment: I called `ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads`, and it always gives numbers between (1019, 1000) and (1023, 1000), even during the hang. `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(500, 500)` has no effect here.

Comment: @Dorus, what's the value of `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count` when it hangs? `GetAvailableThreads` doesn't show actual threads.

Comment: @Noseratio, Starts at 20, goes up to 41 during the hang, then slowly goes back down to 20 and eventually 19.

Comment: @Dorus, I assume this is happening with `SetMinThreads(500, 500)`, correct?

Comment: Correct. If I comment that line out the numbers swing up and down between 18-31, but the end result is still the same.

Comment: @Noseratio good hunch. The thread count should not climb by 21 if there was no blocking. There *is* blocking, just not visible here.

Comment: @usr, I too suspect there's a blocking wait somewhere. Dorus, if you're blaming `Task.Delay`, simply try `Task.Run(() => Sleep(20))` instead, while keeping `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(500, 500)`. Just for the sake of trying, not good for production, of course.

Comment: I've already replaced `Task.Delay(20)` with `Task.Yield(); Thread.Sleep(20)` as a workaround, that works. But yeah, I continue to try to figure out what's going on here because the idea that `Task.Delay(20)` can shoot this far out of line makes it totally unusable. Will try your code tomorrow.

Comment: Try this: 
`var t = new List<Task>(1000); for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)       t.Add(Task.Run(async () => { await Task.Delay(500); })); Task.WhenAll(t).ContinueWith(t1 => { Console.WriteLine("Done!");`
Should complete instantly, as it should. However smaller the delay. Indicating that this is not really a problem with a delay or the number of threads. You are blocking somewhere, or your have a different synchronization context that limits. The community cannot help you unless you post more code!

Comment: Also, if you think that you aren't blocking explicitly, there are many thing that would potentially block implicitly. Like a `lock` for example. Where contention would cause the thread to block. If the contention reaches beyond your CPU architecture's real thread count, it will start having terribly delays (equivalent to what you have shown), since the OS will back pedal your threads. I can say with a high certainty that you're blocking somewhere, either knowingly, or unknowingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing more code, it's hard to make futher guesses, but I'd like to summarize the comments, it may help someone else in the future:

- We've figured out that [the `ThreadPool` stuttering](http://joeduffyblog.com/2006/07/08/clr-thread-pool-injection-stuttering-problems/) is not an issues here, as `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(500, 500)` didn't help.
- Is there any `SynchronizationContext` in place anywhere in your task workflow? Place `Debug.Assert(SyncrhonizationContext.Current == null)` everywhere to check for that. Use `ConfigureAwait(false)` with every `await`.
- Is there any `.Wait`, `.WaitOne`, `.WaitAll`, `WaitAny`, `.Result` used anywhere in your code? Any `lock () { ... }` constructs? `Monitor.Enter/Exit` or any other blocking synchronization primitives?
- Regarding this: *I've already replaced `Task.Delay(20)` with `Task.Yield(); Thread.Sleep(20)` as a workaround, that works. But yeah, I continue to try to figure out what's going on here because the idea that Task.Delay(20) can shoot this far out of line makes it totally unusable.*

  This sounds worrying, indeed. It's very unlikely there's a bug in `Task.Delay`, but everything is possible. For the sake of experimenting, try replacing `await Task.Delay(20)` with `await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(20))`, having `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(500, 500)` still in-place.

  I also have an experimental implementation of `Delay` which uses unamanaged [`CreateTimerQueueTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API (unlike `Task.Delay`, which uses `System.Threading.Timer`, which in turn uses managed `TimerQueue`). It's available [here as a gist](https://gist.github.com/noserati/bf9432246cb9f0122c00). Feel free to try it as `TaskExt.Delay` instead of the standard `Task.Delay`. The timer callbacks are posted to `ThreadPool`, so `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(500, 500)` still should be used for this experiment. I doubt it could make any difference, but I'd be interested to know.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great place for me to start at. I've updated my question.

Comment: @Dorus, not sure if that would change anything, but 1) I wouldn't lock on `tasks` like you do: `task.ContinueWith(_ => { lock (tasks) { tasks.Remove(task); }})`. Create a separate unique `Object` just for use with `lock`. 2) I'd use `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` with `ContinueWith` there (or better yet, `async/await`). 3) What about `SyncrhonizationContext`?

Comment: Yeah, my code is ugly, finally got around to post something minimal. 1) Agreed, makes no difference. 2) Tried this, no difference either. 3) What do you mean?

Comment: @Dorus, regarding `SyncrhonizationContext`, see the second bullet in my answer. What kind of app is that, afterall? (Windows Service, WPF service, Console, WPF, WinForms, etc)

Comment: I cant find any `SyncrhonizationContext`, neither does `ConfigureAwait(false)` make any difference. Even adding await to my `stream.Read` operation makes no difference. Btw, did you see the link to my [code](https://github.com/Dorus/taskDelayProblem)?

Comment: @Dorus, right, there's usually no `SynchronizationContext` in console apps, so one potential problem less. I did have a look the project you posted, but couldn't spot anything too suspicious, besides that you mix async `stream.ReadAsync` and blocking `stream.Read`. Why not do `int r = await stream.ReadAsync(new Byte[750], 0, 750)`?

Comment: That is one of the lines of code I forgot to clean up. The original code used a library that doesn't support async read, so I worked around with that. Already tried to replace it with a single `ReadAsync`.

Comment: Since I'm not expecting more answers, and this one has been very helpful, I will accept it soon. One last question, if I may. Does this look fishy enough that I should follow up on it somewhere else? Some forum? A bug report perhaps? If so, *where* would you suggest to do so?

Comment: @Dorus, if you could create a really self-contained example repro'ing this issue, you should report it at http://connect.microsoft.com.

Comment: [Done](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1164207). Did reduced it as far as I could, hope it was enough.