# Task.Delay(millis) consistently blocks all threads for 100-500ms

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I've noticed firing up several Task.Delay() calls basically "at the same time" causes systematic and periodic long pauses in the execution. Not just in one thread, but all running threads.

Here's an old SO question, which describes probably the same issue: [await Task.Delay(foo); takes seconds instead of ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718362/await-task-delayfoo-takes-seconds-instead-of-ms)

I hope it's ok to re-surface this with a fresh take, since the problem still exists and I haven't found any other workaround than "use Thread.Sleep", which doesn't really work in all cases.

Here's a test code:

```
static Stopwatch totalTime = new Stopwatch();
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task[] tasks = new Task[100];
    totalTime.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = TestDelay(1000, 10, i);
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}

private static async Task TestDelay(int loops, int delay, int id)
{
    int exact = 0;
    int close = 0;
    int off = 0;

    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
    {
        stopwatch.Restart();
        await Task.Delay(delay);

        long duration = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        if (duration == delay) ++exact;
        else if (duration < delay + 10) ++close;
        else
        {
            //This is seen in chunks for all the tasks at once!
            Console.WriteLine(totalTime.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ------ " + id + ": " + duration + "ms");
            ++off;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(totalTime.ElapsedMilliseconds + " -DONE- " + id + " Exact: " + exact + ", Close: " + close + ", Off:" + off);
}
```

By running the code, there will be 1-3 points in time, when all of the N tasks will block/hang/something for significantly more than 10ms, more like 100-500ms. This happens to all tasks, and at the same time. I've added relevant logging, in case someone wants to try it and fiddle with the numbers.

Finally the obvious question is: **Why is this happening, and is there any way to avoid it?** Can anyone run the code and NOT get the delays?

- Tested with dotnetcore 3.1 and net 5.0. Ran on MacOS and Linux.
- Changing min threads doesn't have any effect on this.
- Just for laughs, I tried SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync(millis) (on an always unsignaled semaphore), which funnily enough has the same problem.

EDIT: Here's a sample output:

```
136 ------ 65: 117ms
136 ------ 73: 117ms
160 ------ 99: 140ms
... all 100 of these
161 ------ 3: 144ms
```

Similar output is printed later in the execution as well.

These lines are printed when a task delay takes over 10ms more than requested.
So the first number is the point in time, which is almost the same for all tasks, so I assume it's due to the same hang in execution. The second number is just the task id to tell them apart. Last number is the stopwatch-given delay, which is significantly more than the 10ms.
It can be 10-20ms easily, but 10x is not due to inaccuracy.

I've tried to look into GC problems, but it doesn't happen during a manual GC.Collect(), and when it does happen I don't see changes in heapdump. It's still a possibility, but I'm lost at pinpointing it.

Comment: _"By running the code, there will be 1-3 points in time, when all of the N tasks will block/hang/something for significantly more than 10ms, more like 100-500ms. This happens to all tasks, and at the same time."_ - Sounds like a GC Run to me ...

Comment: ^^ Also: Neither Task.Delay nor Thread.Sleep guarantee an _exact_ amount of "sleepiness". We are not in a real-time system, after all. If you need that, use a real-time system with a real-time language.

Comment: I did not experience any delays at any given time, it seemed everything ran smoothly throughout. Can you be more specific about what you're seeing, for instance showing an example output from the section where you're seeing something unexpected?

Comment: It's easy to copy/paste this code, but I personally have troubles to understand what it does. Mind to explain? Otherwise similar to @LasseV.Karlsen, I fail to see what is the problem with `Delay` exactly on my PC.

Comment: Kind thanks for all the comments so far, I've added an edit.

Comment: @Sinatr, to clarify: it fires off a 100 tasks effectively in parallel (no waiting between starting them). Each task simply waits 10 ms a 1000 times. At the end we wait all 100 to finish. It prints out a line whenever a delay takes more than 20ms. There's also a summary at the end for each task to show that it's mostly very accurate (exact or close), except for 1 or 2 major delays, which happens to all tasks equally.

Comment: I removed all loggins from the code and just collected all duration data in arrays in the `TestDelay` method and then wrote all data into a csv file and plotted the data as a histogram. Now only roughly 0.2% of all delays are over 15 ms off and the mean off is at ~5ms. And the histogram shows that we have two peaks, one at ~0ms off and the second at ~11ms off. So I would think that there is not really a problem, since like Fildor already said `Task.Delay` ist not meant to be exact and I think a mean error of 5ms is okay.

Comment: Also replacing `await Task.Delay(delay)` with `await Task.Yield(); Thread.Sleep(delay)` without moving the `await Task.Yield()` before the `stopwatch.Restart();` makes the performance worse. The mean for me goes up to ~25ms off _Note I didn't changed anything at the config for the thread-pool in either case._

Comment: In which runtime and with which type of application are you testing this? Continuations that run on the thread pool can be delayed because the thread pool does not scale immediately - it tries the remain small.

Comment: @PauloMorgado I've tested on netcore 3.1 and net5.0, with 1 logical core and 12 core machines, all same results. I've seen this happen on simple test ran in VS and a larger app in a self-contaned mode. Your point about Threadpool scaling is very good! That would explain why this happens usually in the beginning of the test, and also why it happens only a couple of times, instead of all the time. Hmm... trying to come up with a way to "warm up" the pool AND keep the number up to see if it helps. ThreadPool.SetMinThreads doesn't do much, seems be more like a soft preference setting.

Comment: It might be also worth checking `Stopwatch.Frequency` and `Stopwatch.IsHighResolution`. If the measured delay is longer then expected at the same time and if there doesn't seam to be a GC problem it might be as well be a problem with the timer.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do the unthinkable, and answer my own question, just in case anyone else stumbles upon this.

First, thanks to @paulomorgado for pointing me towards thread pool latency. That indeed is the problem, if you fire up hundreds of `Task.Delay()` calls in a short period of time.

The way I solved this, was to create a separate `Thread`, which keeps track of requested delays and uses `TaskCompletionSource` to enable asynchronous awaits on the delays.

E.g. create a struct with three fields: start time, delay duration and a TaskCompletionSource. Have the thread loop through these (in a lock) and whenever a duration has expired, mark the task done with `TaskCompletionSource.SetResult()`.

Now you can have a custom async Delay(millis) method that

- creates a new struct
- adds it to a "requested delays" list (lock)
- awaits for the task completion
- remove the struct from the list (lock)
- return

A custom `TaskScheduler` with the needed threads might be a fancier solution, but I found this approach simple and clean. And it seems to do the trick, especially since you can have more than one thread going through all the delays for extra efficiency. Obviously happy to have this approach murdered with any flaws you might notice.

Please note that this approach probably only makes sense if your code is filled with asynchronous delays for some reason (like mine).

**EDIT** Quick sample code for the relevant parts. This needs some optimizing in regards of how locks, loops, news, and lists are handled, but even with this, I can see a HUGE improvement.

With ridiculously short delays (say 10ms), this shows error at 80ms max (tried with 5 threads), where with Task.Delay it's at least 100ms, up to 500ms. With longer, reasonable, delays (100ms+) this is almost flawless, whereas Task.Delay() slaps with the same 100-500ms surprise delay at least in the beginning.

```
private struct CustomDelay
{
    public TaskCompletionSource Completion;
    public long Started;
    public long Delay;
}

//Your favorite data structure here. Using List for clarity. Note: using separate blocks based on delay granularity might be a good idea.
private static List<CustomDelay> _requestedDelays = new List<CustomDelay>();

//Create threads from this. Sleep can be longer if there are several threads.
private static void CustomDelayHandler()
{
    while (_running)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10); //To avoid busy loop

        lock (_delayListLock)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _requestedDelays.Count; ++i)
            {
                CustomDelay delay = _requestedDelays[i];

                if (!delay.Completion.Task.IsCompleted)
                {
                    if (TotalElapsed() - delay.Started >= delay.Delay)
                    {
                        delay.Completion.SetResult();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//Use this instead of Task.Delay(millis)
private static async Task Delay(int ms)
{
    if (ms <= 0) return;

    CustomDelay delay = new CustomDelay()
    {
        Completion = new TaskCompletionSource(),
        Delay = ms,
        Started = TotalElapsed()
    };

    lock (_delayListLock)
    {
        _requestedDelays.Add(delay);
    }

    await delay.Completion.Task;

    lock (_delayListLock)
    {
        _requestedDelays.Remove(delay);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of implementing your own thread pool, you could just [increase the threshold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads) of the existing one: `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias that's true, and is a good point! However I tried that with the original problem (see the question) and it didn't really serve the purpose there. I'm a bit hesitant to use it with the above solution either. Tbh, I'm a bit confused about SetMinThreads, as it appears be more like a "SetPreferredMaxThreads", i.e. pool is increased to that limit if needed (which in my case was too late), and beyond that only in extreme situations.

Comment: Could you include in your answer a minimal example of the working solution? I am very curious how, by adding just one dedicated thread, you solved a problem that 100 `ThreadPool` threads could not solve!

Comment: Sure thing. I'm sure ThreadPool does a way better job in a "normal case", but the problem is with warming up the pool. I'm not sure if there's a robust way to do that. My poor man's solution fixes that and works well in a special case where hundreds of delays need to be handled in a short period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt to reproduce your observations. I am creating 100 tasks, and each task is awaiting repeatedly a 10 msec `Task.Delay` in a loop. The actual duration of each `Delay` is measured with a `Stopwatch`, and is used to update a dictionary that holds the occurrences of each duration (all measurements with the same integer duration are aggregated in a single entry in the dictionary). The total duration of the test is 10 seconds.

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);
const int nominalDelay = 10;
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(10000); // Duration of the test
var durations = new ConcurrentDictionary<long, int>();
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(n => Task.Run(async () =>
{
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    while (true)
    {
        stopwatch.Restart();
        try { await Task.Delay(nominalDelay, cts.Token); }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { break; }
        long duration = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        durations.AddOrUpdate(duration, _ => 1, (_, count) => count + 1);
    }
})).ToArray();
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
var totalTasks = durations.Values.Sum();
var totalDuration = durations.Select(pair => pair.Key * pair.Value).Sum();
Console.WriteLine($"Nominal delay: {nominalDelay} msec");
Console.WriteLine($"Min duration: {durations.Keys.Min()} msec");
Console.WriteLine($"Avg duration: {(double)totalDuration / totalTasks:#,0.0} msec");
Console.WriteLine($"Max duration: {durations.Keys.Max()} msec");
Console.WriteLine($"Total tasks: {totalTasks:#,0}");
Console.WriteLine($"---Occurrences by Duration---");
foreach (var pair in durations.OrderBy(e => e.Key))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Duration {pair.Key,2} msec, Occurrences: {pair.Value:#,0}");
}
```

I run the program on .NET Core 3.1.3, in Release version without the debugger attached. Here are the results:

([Try it on fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wLnNEg))

```xml
Nominal delay: 10 msec
Min duration: 9 msec
Avg duration: 15.2 msec
Max duration: 40 msec
Total tasks: 63,418
---Occurrences by Duration---
Duration  9 msec, Occurrences: 165
Duration 10 msec, Occurrences: 11,373
Duration 11 msec, Occurrences: 21,299
Duration 12 msec, Occurrences: 2,745
Duration 13 msec, Occurrences: 878
Duration 14 msec, Occurrences: 375
Duration 15 msec, Occurrences: 252
Duration 16 msec, Occurrences: 7
Duration 17 msec, Occurrences: 16
Duration 18 msec, Occurrences: 102
Duration 19 msec, Occurrences: 110
Duration 20 msec, Occurrences: 1,995
Duration 21 msec, Occurrences: 14,839
Duration 22 msec, Occurrences: 7,347
Duration 23 msec, Occurrences: 1,269
Duration 24 msec, Occurrences: 166
Duration 25 msec, Occurrences: 136
Duration 26 msec, Occurrences: 264
Duration 27 msec, Occurrences: 47
Duration 28 msec, Occurrences: 1
Duration 36 msec, Occurrences: 5
Duration 37 msec, Occurrences: 8
Duration 38 msec, Occurrences: 9
Duration 39 msec, Occurrences: 7
Duration 40 msec, Occurrences: 3
```

Running the program on .NET Framework 4.8.3801.0 produces similar results.

TL;DR, I was not able to reproduce the 100-500 msec durations you observed.

Comment: Million thanks for experimenting! This is super strange. I ran this test and got avg: 11.2ms, **max:153ms**, and it reported 82,377 tasks. There were 44 durations larger than 100ms (all between 125ms to 153ms). Then I modified my custom delay to support cancellation, set it to 5 threads, and simply changed your test code to use it, and got avg:11.4ms, **max:54ms**, tasks:83,354. Ran on MacOS, 12 cores, target FW: .net5.0. Tested with and without debug. HOWEVER: with debug off, I can see the longer durations with your code only 30% of the time, so that definitely has an effect.

Comment: Another curiosity: I don't see the peaks 10ms apart that your results show. Are you running on Windows? IIRC that has some 10-15ms clock cycle that could cause it, while unix based shenanigans don't have it. Just guessing here.

Comment: @stenu yeap, I ran it on Windows 10, on a 4 core AMD machine. Running it without the debugger is important, otherwise you may not see the behavior of your own program but the behavior of the debugger. Since you are observing peaks even without the debugger, then something really strange happens with your machine IMHO!

Comment: @stenu could it be some interference by the antivirus program? I don't use an antivirus btw.

Comment: No antivirus. My current best guess is that the default scheduler and/or thread pool handler is Windows-optimized (or something along those lines), since I'm seeing the problem on a Mac and on several linux machines. I.e. some sort of OS level hiccup personally coded by Steve Ballmer to smite us blasphemous unix users :) Kidding aside, I'll see if I can find a windows machine somewhere to test it as well.